# Only send openvpn ip private ip traffic through tunnel

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vpn, openvpn

I'm using PIVPN.io as the headend and the current version of openvpn as the client on my ubuntu system.

Here is my config:

```
 client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 45.01.01.01 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
key-direction 1
remote-cert-tls server
tls-version-min 1.2
verify-x509-name server_4EBX2EpXPZasiTv1 name
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
comp-lzo
verb 3
<ca>
```

My ubuntu server (running openvpn client) has two IP addresses,  although they are on the same virtual interface.

How can I only allow the IP traffic 10.8.0.0/24 traffic to pass through the VPN and still allow incoming connections to the server?

For example, if it was running nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this:
Here is a related post:
https://superuser.com/questions/457020/openvpn-only-route-a-specific-ip-addresses-through-vpn

[route-nopull](https://superuser.com/questions/457020/openvpn-only-route-a-specific-ip-addresses-through-vpn)
I added:
`route-nopull`

I also installed NGINX using the following command:

`sudo apt-get install Nginx -y`

After installation, I remained connected to the VPN

My IP address was: `10.8.0.34` and I was successfully able to browse to the webpage using the public IP address, and ping the VPN IP `10.8.0.34`, from the server to the client.

I consider this question 'answered'